# React Native: Getting Extra Grey Bar at the top of UI

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

My code repo is at:

https://github.com/samrao2/manager-4

I am getting an extra grey menu bar at the top and don't know how to get rid of this. My hunch is that this happened because I have an extra scene TAG in my Router.js file but I had to put that in per the recommended solution to solve [this](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/learn/v4/questions/2915290) issue with [this](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/learn/v4/questions/2856464) solution.

Now I am getting an extra grey bar at the top (above "please login" bar) of all my screens, does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhhh, the udemy course....it's a bit outdated.  React-Native-Router-Flux is now based on React-Navigation, so you have to add in a Stack.  Not sure if my code is 'best practice', but this will take care of the grey bar (it stumped me, too.)

```
  <Router sceneStyle={{ paddingTop: 0 }}>
    <Stack key="root" hideNavBar="true">
     <Scene key="auth">
        <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
        <Scene key="createUser" component={CreateUser} title="Create A New Account" />
        <Scene key="password" component={PasswordReset} title="Reset Your Password" />
  </Scene>
    <Scene key="main">
       <Scene
        onRight={() => Actions.employeeCreate()}
        rightTitle="Add"
        key="employeeList"
        component={EmployeeList}
        title="Employees"
        initial
       />
    </Scene>
  </Stack>
</Router>
```

There's a couple more scenes here in my auth key, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly. An additional scene tag also does the job with the same parameters.